# Problems with Singleton implementation

Tags: c++, c++17

Preamble: forgive my english, ty

I'm experimenting with the singleton pattern and so I give you the following snippet of code:

```
// 006 Singleton call_once 01.cpp

//#include "stdafx.h"    // only for Microsoft VS
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>

using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 5;

//#define _CLASSIC_DTOR

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class MySingleton_CallOnce
{
    static MySingleton_CallOnce* theInstance;    
    static  once_flag initiatedInstanceFlag;  
    #ifndef _CLASSIC_DTOR  
        static  once_flag destructedInstanceFlag;
    #endif

    int* ptr;
    
    MySingleton_CallOnce()
    {
        ptr = new int[SIZE];
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
        {
            ptr[i] = (i + 1) * 10;
        }
    }


    static void createAndInit()            
    {
        theInstance = new MySingleton_CallOnce();
    }

    #ifndef _CLASSIC_DTOR
    void myDelete()
    {
        delete[] ptr;
    }
    #endif

public:
    ~MySingleton_CallOnce()
    {
        #ifdef _CLASSIC_DTOR
            delete[] ptr; // Exception with 2nd call
        #else
            call_once(destructedInstanceFlag, &MySingleton_CallOnce::myDelete,this);
        #endif

    }

    static MySingleton_CallOnce* getInstance()
    {

        call_once(initiatedInstanceFlag, createAndInit);    
        return theInstance;
    }

    MySingleton_CallOnce(const MySingleton_CallOnce& src) = delete;
    MySingleton_CallOnce& operator=(const MySingleton_CallOnce& src) = delete;

};


MySingleton_CallOnce* MySingleton_CallOnce::theInstance = nullptr;
once_flag MySingleton_CallOnce::initiatedInstanceFlag;

#ifndef _CLASSIC_DTOR
    once_flag MySingleton_CallOnce::destructedInstanceFlag;
#endif
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main()
{

    {   
        MySingleton_CallOnce* p = MySingleton_CallOnce::getInstance();

        MySingleton_CallOnce* q = MySingleton_CallOnce::getInstance();

        delete p;

        delete q;    // guilty statement
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here the code: [Link to Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b543da531d0d386b)

I know that it's twisted code but I repeat: I'm experimenting, and though I'll never write this code in production I suppose that if I'll understand what's going on here (and/or what's not going on) somewhat will be clarified in my mind about C++ behind the scenes.

I suppose that everybody can guess the intentions of this code but for the sake of clarity I'll try to explain how I came to this code:

- **1st attempt**: I wrote the code with _CLASSIC_DTOR defined and so the destructor simply calls delete[] ptr.

  My main() declares and uses 2 pointer and so - in the end - I release these 2 pointers.
  Obviously in this particular case (singleton !) the problem is: you can't release twice the same resource and so the 2nd delete is the guilty statement: commenting it everything it's ok.
- **2nd attempt**: _CLASSIC_DTOR now is NOT defined.

  I don't like declare and use 2 pointer but release only one of them, so I decided to use "std::call_once()" in the destructor; then I crossed the code with the debugger, step by step, and everything seems to be fine:

1. When I call "delete p;" then is called call_once(...) in the destructor and is executed myDelete function
2. When I call "delete q;" then is called call_once (...) in the distructor BUT
   this time myDelete is not called ( and this was what I wanted in order to avoid the release of the chunk of heap already released with "delete p;") BUT when the destructor ends Microsoft VS throws the message: "006 Singleton call_once 01.exe has triggered a breakpoint."
   Also in this case if I comment the guilty statement "delete q;" everything is fine.

Can someone explain to me the reason for this message?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: `p == q`. After `delete p`, both are dangling pointers. Then `delete q` exhibits undefined behavior, by way of accessing an object after its lifetime has ended. Practically speaking, `delete q` is not only calling the destructor, it's also deallocating memory - in this case, memory that has already been deallocated once.

Comment: In the end, this is little different than `int* p = new int{42}; delete p; delete p;`

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik; sure, but when _CLASSIC_DTOR is not defined std::call_once() is called 2 times and the 2nd call does not invoke myDelete() {delete[] ptr;}, So, why this code is problematic?

Comment: In the first `MySingleton_CallOnce::getInstance()` call, two memory allocations are performed - one for `MySingleton_CallOnce` instance itself, and the other in the constructor for the array of 5 ints. In `delete p`, both are deallocated - the `int` array by `delete[] ptr` call in `myDelete`, the memory for `MySingleton_CallOnce` instance as a natural effect of `delete` operator. In `delete q`, `myDelete` is not called, but the memory formerly occupied by `MySingleton_CallOnce` instance is still being deallocated - again. This exhibits undefined behavior, and the heap manager complains.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik: you are right. TY